# Animation of binary number using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is it possible to archieve the following animation (http://www.motionbackgroundsforfree.com/technology-free-backgrounds/free-technology-background-binary-horizon/) using CSS (and/or HTML5/JQuery/Javascript)?

Would like to have a full screen background with binaries flowing out on the right side as a loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lines = 10;
  var textLength = 40;

  for (i = 0; i < lines - 1; i++) {
    $(".num").first().clone().insertAfter($(".num").first());
  }


  setInterval(function() {
    $(".num").each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().length < textLength) {
        $(this).text(($(this).text() + Math.round(Math.random())));
      } else {
        $(this).text(Math.round(Math.random()) + $(this).text().substring(0, $(this).text().length - 1))
      }
    });

  }, 75);

});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6z5y08nk/)

You can tune it up further :)

Comment: Look nice. Trying to understand the JQuery stuff, but I will get there :-). I also try to fill the whole browser width/height and scale the text accordingly to the browser window size. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: Use css to resize the elements :D

Answer (score 1):

### Pure CSS(3) solution

Yes, it is possible.

CSS3 will help a lot, using [3D Transform](http://rotateX()%20rotateY()%20rotateZ()) like

```
rotateX()
rotateY()
rotateZ()
```

Then play with basic animations and transitions to move you bits.

### EDIT

Here is a start : https://jsfiddle.net/Alteyss/ks1vyL9k/

Comment: I'm quite new in the web-development area (I do IOS/Swift programming). Can you point me into the right direction on how to do the math og maybe some code to make me start? Thx